# AJAX call on dropdown value doesn't display data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to using AJAX call function and I am trying to figure out why my dropdown list does not display the data from my database. Okay, the scenario is that I have 2 dropdown list in my form. the first is to select a 'Specialization' and the second is to select a doctor. When I select a specialization, it will load the list of doctors under that particular specialization. The function of the AJAX call is to call the doctors' name in the doctor dropdown list. I am unable to make the list of doctors appear in my dropdown list.

Here are the code for my specialization dropdown list:

```
<div>
  <label>Doctor Specilization</label>
  <select name="specilization" id="specilization" onBlur="getspec()" autocomplete="off" required>
    <?php 
                  $sqlspecili = "SELECT S_NAME FROM tblspecilization";
                      $speciliquery = $dbh -> prepare($sqlspecili);
                      $speciliquery->execute();
                      $speciliresults=$speciliquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                      $specilicnt=1; ?>

    <option selected hidden value="">Select specialization</option>
    <?php if($speciliquery->rowCount() > 0) {
                        foreach($speciliresults as $speciliresults) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($speciliresults->S_NAME);?>">
      <?php echo htmlentities($speciliresults->S_NAME);?> </option>
    <?php $specilicnt=$specilicnt+1;
                          }
                        } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

And this is the code for my doctor dropdown list:

```
<div>
  <label>Select Doctor</label>
  <select name="doctor" id="get_doctor_name" autocomplete="off" required>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is the script for my AJAX call:

```
    <script>
      function getspec() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "get_doctor.php",
          data: 'specilization=' + $("#specilization").val(),
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#get_doctor_name").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
          },
          error: function() {}
        });
    </script>
```

This is the `get_doctor.php` which is called in the AJAX call:

```
<?php
include('incl/conn.php');
if(!empty($_POST['specilization'])) 
{
    $specilization =:$_POST['specilization'];

    $sql = "SELECT D_ID, D_NAME FROM tbldoctor 
            WHERE D_SPECILIZATION=:specilization";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':specilization',$specilization,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    <option selected="selected">Select Doctor</option>
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) 
    {
        foreach($results as $results) 
            { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($results->D_ID);?>" >
                <?php echo htmlentities($results->D_NAME);?>
            </option> <?php
            }
    }
    else
    { ?>
        <option value=""> No Doctor in this specilization</option>
        <?php echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>"; 
    }
}?>
```

This is the SQL table for `tbldoctor`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbldoctor` (
  `D_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `D_SPECILIZATION` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `D_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `D_GENDER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D_ADDRESS` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `D_FEES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D_CONTACTNO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D_EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D_USERNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `D_PASSWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `D_CREATIONDATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `D_LASTLOGIN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

This is the table for `tblspecilization`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblspecilization` (
  `S_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `S_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `S_CREATIONDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
)
```

Comment: You have a number of places that could "go wrong" - eg the ajax call, the php that receives the ajax call, the php that looks up the data, the php that returns the data, the js that receives the result.  You should be able to narrow down to which of those is causing the problem with some basic debugging (step-through or logging).  Without this focus, it's too vague.

Comment: I only use two page for this code. first page is the `book-appointment.php` that contains my form and the ajax call script. second page is the `get_doctor.php`. Is this helpful in narrowing down the possibilities of error?

Comment: The files are irrelevant, it's the point in code.  Only you can debug these.

Comment: get_doctor.php has issues, you are not closing php on line 15, if you want to this way, best is to use echo to print options,

Comment: and its more easy to just load result in ajax and loop through it to print options, less complex

Comment: @AhmedSunny , how do i echo the print options? I tried to drag options into the `echo " "` like this `echo "<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($results->D_ID);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($results->D_NAME);?></option> <?php";` but it still didnt work. And you are correct. I have gotten confused with where to put the `<?php ?>` tag

Comment: this is wrong, i added it in answer, check there, here i cant add  completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't make it too complex .there are multiple  ways to do this, but this `echo "<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($results->D_ID);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($results->D_NAME);?></option> <?php";`  is wrong
dont confuse yourself with closing,opening of php tags, try the following

```
<?php
include('incl/conn.php');
if(!empty($_POST['specilization'])) 
{
    $specilization =:$_POST['specilization'];

    $sql = "SELECT D_ID, D_NAME FROM tbldoctor 
            WHERE D_SPECILIZATION=:specilization";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':specilization',$specilization,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    echo '<option selected="selected">Select Doctor</option>';
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) 
    {
        foreach($results as $results) 
            { 
            echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($results->D_ID).'">'. htmlentities($results->D_NAME).'</option>'; 
            }
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<option value=""> No Doctor in this specilization</option>';
       echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thankyou for sharing the simpler code. I highly appreciate it. However, the doctor dropdown list doesnt show. I don't know where to start to find the error as I am not familiar on the ajax call.

Comment: open browser console and see network tab, when you select an option in first dropdown, the ajax request will be send, check in the response,

Comment: am I doing it right by using ` type: "POST" ` in the ajaxcall?

Comment: yes, POST is fine, but the thing you need to check is  that, 1.are you receiving post? if yes then whats the response you getting back.you can check both in console/network tab

Comment: It worked! Thankyou so much! I received an error which i have to remove the `:` in the `$specilization =:$_POST['specilization'];` and after that the code works. Thankyou. Hope you'll have a good day :)

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to use the same function `getspec()` to retrieve data from 2 different IDs like `id=get_doctor_name` and another dropdown list with id of `id=get_doctor_assistant`? both IDs are from 2 different tables.

Comment: yes, but would not be logical, as tables are different, then you would have an if in the function to differentiate which table to call, so better make 2 function, you should have same function for multiple thing when they have something in common, to reduce redundancy,